# What's NUL-bombing my console during shutdown?

Tags: fedora, suspend

When I shut down Fedora Linux, I see the following sequence:

1. <del>Listings of things being shut down.</del>
2. `^@^@^@^@` etc, across half the top line of the screen.
3. Many [repeated](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/c6e4724/src/core/shutdown.c#L230) messages about not being able to shut down device mapper nodes
4. An apparently successful clean shutdown.

Point 2 is annoying.  What causes this?

Does it happen on every install?

I assume this is a rendering of the NUL character (code 0).

I count 38 repetitions of `^@` in this photograph.

- Fedora Workstation 25.
- Intel graphics using KMS (`inteldrmfb` in `/proc/fb`).
- 64 bit kernel, userspace, and UEFI.
- systemd-231-14.fc25.x86_64
- plymouth-0.9.3-0.6.20160620git0e65b86c.fc25.x86_64
- kernel-4.10.10-200.fc25.x86_64

[image: A text console, showing ^@^@^@^@ across half of the first line]

EDIT: If I shut down immediately after start-up, this does not happen.  If I suspend and resume the machine once before shutdown, there is one `^@`.

Comment: Compare https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396192/ .

Comment: @JdeBP `lsmod` or `ls /sys/module` does not show either `peaq_wmi` (this is a Dell, not a PEAQ), nor `input_polldev`.  It seems  bit odd for it to be an input problem, as it seems to occur on a VT where console echo appears to be disabled 99% of the time.  (systemd boot generally does not appear to leave console echo enabled until starting a getty, and my VT1 doesn't have a getty because it has gdm running on it instead).