# ^@ spam in tty (but seems to be system-wide)

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, tty, i3

I recently noticed some weird behavior on my GNU/Linux machine. I've been trying to narrow it down but I am unsure where to go next. My setup uses the following:

- i3
- gdm
- arch
- systemd
- grub2
- pulseaudio
- 4.13.3-1-ARCH

Here is how it manifests iself:

- when trying to resize panes in i3 (alt+right click and hold) the action will be randomly canceled (happens on key presses)
- alt+dragging windows meets a similar fate
- booting to tty periodically adds ^@s to the login prompt, I'd estimate them to be ~0.5s intervals
- in tty I can see those being passed to vim when I open the command bar (:)
- using a pager like less in tty mode and searching with / will result in  (?) being spammed
- htop's search (/) is instantly canceled by the periodic keypress
- holding a key and trying to have it be repeated (such as holding space) will stop the other occurrences from happening (e.g. only one or two happen)
- any tooltip (such as chrome tooltips) get instantly closed because of key presses

Here is what I have tried:

- tried switching DE temporarily (gnome, cinnamon, xfce)
- tried killing programs one by one until I was left with a tty session and essentially systemd services + pulseaudio
- tried booting on an arch livecd - problem does not manifest
- overriding grub2 with init=/bin/bash drops me into a shell where the problem does not manifest
- I have tried pressing all keys to verify it wasn't a hardware problem, however previous steps point to it not being hardware
- I have made a diff of dmesg, from the init=/bin/bash and the regular boot - the main difference seems to be systemd being started in the regular boot
- Made a diff of lsmod from init=/bin/bash and regular boot, tried to rmmod modules that seemed related

My system is up to date, I'm not quite sure what other steps I can do to track this down. Any other debugging tips?

Comment: Well I'll be damned, I am not used to hanging out on those forums - this fixed it; if you can type a summary of the fix in an answer format then you should - I'd market it as accepted

Comment: If I recall correctly I need 24 hours to approve it, but I will :) Thanks.

Comment: Compare https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395494/ .

Comment: It looks like the same issue, I'm also on a lenovo if it helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 4.13, `+CONFIG_PEAQ_WMI=m` was added to the vanilla kernel, a dependency of `CONFIG_INPUT_POLLDEV`. This has resulted in regressions for various types of systems, including the console spamming you experienced. It appears to have been introduced [with this commit](https://www.spinics.net/lists/kernel/msg2571180.html).

Blacklisting `input_polldev` is the current workaround.

Comment: A [link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230340) to the Arch forum discussion.